# iPad : UIPageViewController navigationOrientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I want the navigationOrientation of my `UIPageViewController` to change when I change the orientation of my `UIViewController`. That is, when the device is rotated to portrait I want the `navigationOrientation` to change from `UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical` to `UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal`.

I tried setting `navigationOrientation` property on rotation of the view controller but I found that `navigationOrientation` property is read-only.

Here are the images what I want.

**Landscape View**
[image: Landscape View]

**Portrait View**
[image]

What should I do ?

Comment: Use should use the autoresize in xib .

Comment: @vishiphone: How autoresizing would help his problem? Did you understand that he want split of the page to change from vertical to horizontal?

Comment: @ParthBhatt I think he just want to rotate the View like orientation because his image and question like that only.

Comment: He will show the image of portriat and landscape view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

Don't know why, but it seems as if Apple doesn't want you to change that property. Either technical reasons or some sort of UI-guideline.

Anyway if you cannot change the orientation you should go with a different approach and use **two** `UIPageViewControllers`, each with another navigation orientation, which share one delegate. On device turn you hide/show the corresponding views or you init/release a new object each device turn.

BTW. Did you have a look at the `pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:` method of the delegate. Seems as if Apple's preferred way of reacting to device orientation changes is this one:

> **Discussion** Use this method to change the spine location when the
>   device orientation changes, as well as setting new view controllers
>   and changing the double-sided state.
>
> This method is called only if the transition style is
>   `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`.

Note that Apple's calendar app goes with very slim pages in portrait - seems really to be their idea of UI.

Comment: Yes, Apple calendar like view can be done by removing "if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))"

Comment: Don't know exactly what you mean, but the calendar app **does** react on device orientation change. It changes the view(controllers) for each page when device turns. You can see that by the monthly overview switching from left to right page.

Comment: @Devang Hi Devang, i need something similar like your requirement. What i am doing is i am having five view controllers added in array and using page view controller to show two views on screen at a time like you did in first image. I am having landscape view fixed for my app. What i want is after showing four view controllers it will show single view controller on landscape. Can you guide me for that, my rest functionality is done only this portion i could not solve yet.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue in a slightly different way, I inherited UIPageViewController class and override the initWithCoder as follows:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    NSDictionary *options = nil;

    if ([self isLandscapeOrientation])
    {
        options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid] forKey:UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];
    }

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    return [super initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:options];
}

- (BOOL)isLandscapeOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation);
}
```